# Image to display while dragging

Tags: c++, winapi, drag-and-drop

I am implementing drag and drop of button on windows application.During dragging I want to display some dragging effect. I think image of the button would be appropriate to display during dragging.

Also I think cursor should be changed during dragging.

My doubts are:
How to capture the image of button and display while dragging.
What type of cursor should be displayed during dragging.

Application is in C++, win32.

Answer (score 0):

1. Drag image:

   If it is a standard button control then you should be able to use [WM_PRINT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145216%28VS.85%29.aspx) or [WM_PRINTCLIENT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145217%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) to ask it to draw itself to a GDI HDC (i.e. into a bitmap that you then use as the drag-image).

   Note that not all controls support those messages and some of them support them in slightly different ways. Sometimes you have to experiment a bit or have custom code-paths for different controls.

   Another way is to draw the button yourself using the visual styles (themes) API, with a fallback on [DrawFrameControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162480%28VS.85%29.aspx) for when themes are disabled. But that is much more tedious than using WM_PRINT/WM_PRINTCLIENT if you don't need it.
2. Cursor:

   Depends what the operation is doing, really. Note that you get the copy and move cursors for free with the shell drag object, if you want them. Sometimes it makes sense to use a custom cursor, though.